# question about eigenvalue on quotient space (from Linear Algebra done Right)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'am study the algebra,but have some question for the exercise5.A

> 35. Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $\def\L{\mathcal L}T\in\L(V)$, and $U$ is invariant under$~T$. Prove that each eigenvalue of $T/U$ is an eigenvalue of$~T$.
>
> [*The exercise below asks you to verify that the hypothesis that $V$ is finite-dimensional is needed for the exercise above.*]
>
> 36. Given an example of a vector space $V$, and operator $T\in\L(V)$ and a subspace $U$ of$~V$ that is invariant under $T$ such that $T/U$ has an eigenvalue that is not an eigenvalue of$~T$.

How to solve the question? I'm puzzling how to define eigenvalue of $T/U$, especially $T/U(v+U) = λv+U$ when $v$ also in $U$?
THANKS!

Comment: $T|U$ means $T$ restricted to the subspace $U$ (not the quotient space)

Comment: @Muralidharan:T|U means T restricted to the subspace U,it's right!But my question is indeed a type of quotient space from the book of Linear Algebra done Right 3rd.From book,T/U(v+U)=T(v)+U,so puzzle for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (not entirely standard) notation $T/U$ means the action induced by $T$ on the quotient space $V/U$, in other words $v+U\mapsto T(v)+U$, which is well defined because $T(v+u)\in T(v)+U$ for any $u\in U$ since $U$ is $T$-stable.

An eigenvector of $T/U$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a coset $v+U$, distinct from $0+U=U$ (since eigenvectors cannot be zero; so you are not allowed to take $v\in U$ as you say in the question), such that $T/U(v+U)=\lambda(v+U)=\lambda(v)+U$. This says that $T(v)+U=\lambda v+U$; note that this does not imply that $v$ itself is an eigenvector of$~T$, so the question is not entirely trivial.

So suppose $v\notin U$ and $\lambda$ are given with $T(v)+U=\lambda v+U$.
Note that this means that not just $U$, but also the sum $V'=\langle v\rangle\oplus U$ is $T$-stable: $T$ sends both any vector in $U$ and the vector $v$ into this sum$~V'$. I will show that $V'$ already contains an eigenvector for$~\lambda$ of$~T$ (so $V$ certainly does too).
Consider the minimal polynomial $\mu$ of the restriction$~T|_U$ of $T$ to $U$. If it has $\lambda$ as root, then the restriction already has an eigenvector for$~\lambda$ of$~T$, and we are done without even using the fact that $v+U$ is an eigenvector of$~T/U$. Suppose henceforth that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of$~T|_U$, so that $\mu[\lambda]$ is a nonzero scalar. Since $T/U$ acts on the coset $v+U$ as multiplication by$~\lambda$, we get that $\mu[T/U]$ acts on that coset as multiplication by that nonzero scalar $\mu[\lambda]$, sending it to the coset $\mu[\lambda]v+U\neq U$; so in particular $\mu[T](v)\neq0$, and $\mu$ cannot (also) be the minimal polynomial $\mu'$ of the restriction$~T|_{V'}$ of $T$ to$~V'$. On the other hand $\mu'$ must be a polynomial multiple of $\mu$ (since $\mu'[T]$ must in particular kill vectors of $U$), and $\mu(X-\lambda)$, is an annihilating polynomial for$~T|_{V'}$, because $\mu[T]\circ(T-\lambda I)$ kills both $U$ and $v$ (the latter because $T(v)+U=\lambda v+U$ means $T(v)-\lambda v\in U$ which is killed by $\mu[T]$). But then $\mu(X-\lambda)$ is minimal polynomial $\mu'$ of$~T|_V'$, and since it has $\lambda$ as root, it follows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the restriction $T|_{V'}$ (since any root of the minimal polynomial is an eigenvalue), and therefore also of$~T$. (Indeed once easily shows that the nonzero vector $\mu[T](v)\in V'$ is an eigenvector for$~\lambda$ of$~T$.)

---

The above proof may seem difficult, so I will propose some alternatives.

If you choose a basis for $V$ that starts with a basis for $U$ and completes that, then expressed on this bases $T$ has a block upper triangular form
$$ \pmatrix{A&*\\0&B},$$
where $A$ is the matrix of the restriction $T|_U$, and $B$ is the matrix of $T/U$, with respect to the basis of $V/U$ obtained from the second part of our basis for$~V$. Now by a property of determinants for block triangular matrices, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_T$ of $T$ is the product of the characteristic polynomials $\chi_A$ of $A$ and $\chi_B$ of $B$. By hypothesis the latter has a root$~\lambda$, hence so does $\chi_T$.

I did not propose this proof, because Axler is well known not to like determinants, and correspondingly should detest having to use characteristic polynomials.

---

If you know about left- (rather than the usual right-) eigenvectors, this is almost immediate. Whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for$~T$ acting on a finite dimensional vector space, there is not only some eigenvector $v\in V$ for$~\lambda$, but also a left eigenvector: a linear form $\phi\in V^*$ such that $\phi\circ T=\lambda\phi$. But a left eigenvector of $T/U$ for $\lambda$, which is a linear form $\phi:V/U\to K$ immediately gives a left eigenvector $\tilde\phi=\phi\circ\pi$ where $\pi:V\to V/U$ is the canonical projection, as the following manipulation shows:
$$\tilde\phi\circ T=\phi\circ\pi\circ T
 =\phi\circ T/U\circ\pi=\lambda\phi\circ\pi=\lambda\tilde\phi.
$$
But the fact that whenever there is a right eigenvector for$~\lambda$ there is also a left eigenvector, and vice versa, is a result that is about equivalent to the question at hand, so this answer is not really satisfying.

---

For an example of what goes wrong in infinite dimension, take one of the easiest cases where injectivity and surjectivity of a linear operator are not the same: the shift-down and shift-up operators on infinite sequences of scalars. It suffices to consider finitely supported sequences (finitely many nonzero terms), which can be modelled by polynomials, so take $V=K[X]$; the shift-down operator $S$ consist of removing the constant term and then dividing by$~X$, while the shift-up operator $T$ is multiplication by$~X$. Clearly $S$ is not injective (constant polynomials are killed) but it is surjective, while $T$ is injective (no polynomial is killed by multiplying it by$~X$) but not surjective (any image has zero constant term). Being injective means that $T$ has no eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ (nor does it has any other eigenvalue for that matter). However $T$ has plenty of stable subspaces, for instance $U$ could be the set of polynomials divisible by $X^7$. Since every polynomial enters into $U$ after at most $7$ applications of$~T$, the induced operator $T/U$ is nilpotent, and does have an eigenvector for $\lambda=0$ (indeed $\overline v=X^6+U$ has $T(\overline v)=X^7+U=U$, the zero vector in $V/U$), answering the second question.

I did not do anything with the shift-down operator $S$, but it provides an example of the existence of a right eigenvector for $\lambda=0$ (any nonzero constant polynomial) without any corresponding left eigenvector (a linear form $\phi$ on the polynomials killed by right-composition with $S$ would have to vanish on the image$~S(V)=V$, implying $\phi=0$). So that is why the last argument above requires finite dimension; the others use minimal and characteristic polynomials, which only exist (in general) for linear operators on finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Interesting. What reasons are there to not like determinants?

Comment: So nice,also axler!I'm studying the anwsers.

Comment: I'm enjoying the questions with you!The second quesion is why V must be  finite dimensional?

Comment: Also I'm puzzled for:if T/U(u+U)=λu+U,so T/U(u+U)=λu+U=(λ+1)u+U=U;so λ,λ+1,λ+2.... all are  eigenvalue ?

Comment: @jun: I don't get that last comment. If $u\in U$ as the name suggests, then $u+U=U$ is the zero vector of $V/U$, which is forbidden as eigenvector.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen you are right!

Comment: I understand the method of left- (rather than the usual right-) eigenvectors

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use (and prove) that $\chi_T(X) = \chi_{T/U}(X)\cdot \chi_{T|_U}(X)$, where $\chi_f(X)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of the linear map $f$.

Comment: Very nice,I'll try!